# Is there statistical data on 'review task' to ban ratio?

Tags: discussion, review, review-audits

I wanted to compare myself to others to see how well I am performing (or rather under-performing) on doing review tasks. I am assuming that averages will represent total data well enough, as I would expect data to be normally distributed.

Is there any chance on getting data on:

- What is average review count before one gets his first ban?
- How often does one get a ban (how many reviews result in a ban)?

Comment: If you know how to review you get never banned. If you do from time to time then you don't do it too well

Comment: @juergend Knowledgeable reviewers get never banned!?!  That doesn't sound good.  =p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll just look at Stack Overflow to answer this, since it's easier that way.

89% of reviewers have done less than 100 reviews, 75 have done less than 10 and 52% have done exactly *one* - so there's a really long tail there, with a lot of reviews being done by a lot of people doing just a little.

97% of reviewers have never been banned. For reviewers with at least 100 reviews under their belt, 75% of them have never been banned. By the time you get to 1000 reviews, only 59% will have failed to encounter a ban at least once.

Given this distribution, it shouldn't surprise you to learn that the *average* number of reviews before the first ban is 629. Remember too, folks tend to get audited repeatedly before they get banned, so they tend to learn what not to do (which is the whole *point* of auditing). The audit you report failing wasn't the first one you've failed either.

Finally, here's a breakdown of bans per 100 reviews by the number of reviewers in each category (this includes only that ~11% of reviewers who've done at least 100 reviews):

```
BansPer100Reviews Reviewers 
----------------- --------- 
0                 7263      
1                 2113      
2                 221       
3                 50        
4                 16        
5                 9         
6                 3         
7                 2
```

Comment: Hi Shog9, thanks for the data. Am I correct to assume that you have used `round()` for BansPer100Reviews, and those that get 1 ban per 200+ reviews fall into group `0 - 7263`?

Comment: No, i used `ceiling()`